# scipy sparse matrix and sparsesvd

Tags: python, scipy

I have a sparse matrix M 
when I run `type(M)`, I get

```
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

However, when I use the matrix in `sparesvd` function as

```
U, S, Vt = sparsesvd(M, K)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a scipy.sparse.csc_matrix
```

Are those two not the same types?

Comment: `csc_matrix` and `csr_matrix` are not the same.  They store the data in different formats.  Try `U, S, Vt = sparsesvd(M.tocsc(), K)`

Comment: Where does `sparsesvd` come from?  There is no function with that name scipy.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparsesvd/.  It prominently says: *sparsesvd uses SciPy’s sparse CSC (Compressed Sparse Column) matrix format as input to SVD.*

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser my dyslexia is showing! I did not even notice the letters are different. Thank you.